# summarize() is producing NA values

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

`summarize()` isn't working all that well. It is working for one kind of penguin, the Chinstrap penguin. It isn't working for the others.

This is what I wrote:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library("tidyverse")

install.packages("palmerpenguins")
library("palmerpenguins")

 penguins %>% 
  group_by(species) %>%
  summarize(average_bill_length = mean(bill_length_mm), 
        average_bill_depth = mean(bill_depth_mm), 
        average_body_mass = mean(body_mass_g))
```

This is what I got:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  species   average_bill_length average_bill_depth average_body_mass
  <fct>                   <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>
1 Adelie                   NA                 NA                 NA 
2 Chinstrap                48.8               18.4             3733.
3 Gentoo                   NA                 NA                 NA
```

I tried installing and loading the dplyr package. It still gives the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume you expect there to not be `NA` values in your output. Try adding `na.rm = TRUE` to your lines where you calculate the mean e.g. `mean(bill_depth_mm, na.rm = TRUE)`. (Or remove rows with `NA` values in those columns first.)

Comment: As @nrennie comments, it would helpful to know what you _want_ to get.  The output you post is the correct output from your code.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: The behavior is correct because you cannot know the average bill length of your penguins if you ignore the bill length of 1 or more of them. You might choose to ignore it and compute the average with the other observations but you have to be careful because the distributions of these unknowns might not be random. Imagine they couldn't measure the length because their rulers were not long enough, your average would be biased. So you need to opt in carefully with `na.rm = TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I used drop_na() and it worked! It was the NAs that were creating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Thank you so much for your guidance. I used `drop_na()` and it worked! It was the NAs that were creating the issue - [Sonam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669151/summarize-is-producing-na-values#comment135180565_76669151)

If dropping NAs is appropriate, which it often isn't- (how can you, say, find the average height of a group of people if you don't know the height of one of them?), then you can drop NAs with either the `drop_na` function above or in some functions like `mean` by passing the argument `na.rm = TRUE` (check the documentation for each function, to see if it has this possibility)
[Credit: nrennie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669151/summarize-is-producing-na-values#comment135171994_76669151)